# ¿Cómo parar el responsive de la pantalla en un tamaño específico?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive, mediaqueries

Soy novato en CSS, estoy utilizando Bootstrap 4, mi duda es ¿cómo parar el responsive de la pantalla en un tamaño especifico?

Cada vez que se hace más pequeña la pantalla cada vez se va encojiendo todo y queda mas apretado, ¿cómo logro que en un tamaño especifico deje de tratar de adaptarse a la pantalla del dispositivo?

Es como que si la pantalla se volviera un `overflow: auto;` y se pudiera recorrer la web arrastrando el mouse y para la adaptabilidad a la pantalla del dispositivo. No se si me explico...

De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!

Comment: Te recomiendo que coloques algo de codigo, ademas de leer la documentacion de bootstrap--> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal

Comment: La grid de bootstrap no me ayuda en este caso en especifico...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro de entender lo que dices de "parar" pero si lo que quieres, es que llegado unas dimensiones, no siga ajustandose, utiliza las llamadas MediaQuery. Son asi:

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Con esto, lo que puedes hacer, es poner min-width:400px y cuando llegue al numero de px, dejara de ejecutarse el codigo. Te dejo el enlace para que puedas ver mas ejemplos.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Lo prove y no funciona, no pasa nada...

Comment: @JulioCesar Edita tu pregunta y Sube el código que tienes, ya que con eso podemos ver mejor que estas haciendo y en donde radica tu error ,a demás lo que pone **Cupax64** debería de solucionar tu problema

Comment: No tengo ningun error, solo quiero saber como lograr lo que explique en mi pregunta... Copie el codigo de @cupax64 y no vi ningun cambio, no sucedio nada... no se que esta pasando la verdad.

Comment: Prove de nuevo el codigo y funciono! No se que paso, pero puse a 200px y funciona pero a 600px no pasa nada... cuando pongo a 200px funciona pero funciona al reves, logro el resultado pero con pantalla grande.. no quiero que suceda eso, no se que esta pasando...

Comment: @JulioCesar de igual forma sube el codigo las preguntas sin codigo no son bien recibidas en la comunidad ademas con el codigo podemos ver que es lo que falla o darte mejores ejemplos

Comment: Ok pero css o el html?

Comment: Lo que dices de 600px y 200px es el tamaño de la pantalla. Significa que entre 200px y 600px se ejecutara el codigo que haya dentro, si la pantalla esta a 199px o menos y a 601px o mas, no se ejecuta. Esto se hace por ejemplo para los menus que ves en web, que esta todo en horizontal, y cuando llegan a una medida movil, que aparezcan las 3 rayas y el menu sea desplegable. Suerte con tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

si utilizas boostrap 4 , creo que deberias aprovechar los breakpoints de grid .

```html
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
   </div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/